# insert after child libxml perl

Tags: xml, perl

```
<root>
 <element>abc</element>
<top>
 <element>after</element>
<element>before</element>
</top>
 <element>456</element>
</root>
```

I  want to insert another element after element and before element.
Tried a few variations, must be missing something.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;
my $doc = $parser->parse_file("mytest.xml");
my $root = $doc->getDocumentElement();
my @node = $doc->find('//top/element[2]');

my $new_element= $doc->createElement("element");
$new_element->appendText('testing');

$node[0]->insertAfter($new_element, undef);

print $root->toString(1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$node[0]` is the referenced node (i.e. the node relative to which we want to insert). Let's call it `$ref_node` instead.

Your code suffers from the following problems:

- You want to insert after the first `element` of `top`, not the second.
- You want to insert it as a child of `$ref_node->parentNode`, not `$ref_node`.
- You want to insert it after `$ref_node`, not after `undef`.
- You're also using `find` (which returns a NodeList) when you want `findnodes` (which returns the actual nodes).

So,

```
my ($ref_node) = $doc->findnodes('//top/element[1]');
$ref_node->parentNode->insertAfter($new_element, $ref_node);
```

Comment: answer returns = Can't locate object method "parentNode" via package "XML::LibXML::NodeList".
Note: I was getting this quite a bit on some of my variations.

Comment: @Paul: So there are several nodes matching the XPath.

Comment: Not that I see, see given XML and XPATH. But it appears find returns nodelist with given xpath regardless. Note, this too gives me same error my @ref_node = $doc->find('//top/element[2]');
$ref_node[0]->parentNode->insertAfter($new_element, $ref_node[0]);

Comment: @Paul, You also have to change `find` to `findnodes`. Adjusted my answer.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;
my $doc = $parser->parse_file("mytest.xml");
my $root = $doc->getDocumentElement();
my ($ref_node) = $doc->find('//top/element[2]');

my $new_element= $doc->createElement("element");
$new_element->appendText('testing');
$ref_node->parentNode->insertAfter($new_element, $ref_node);#error thrown

print $root->toString(1);

Comment: @Paul, You also have to change `find` to `findnodes`, and change `element[2]` to `element[1]`.

Comment: For information as it might help someone, thanks to this answer I understood that to use insertAfter, one needs to use the parent node object of where to the sibling will be added. Initially I was using the top dom object since the manual page does not clarify which object must be used.

Comment: @Jacques, hmm... You obviously need to specify to what you element you want to add the node! All the append/insert methods are called on the element to which the node should be added.

Comment: @Jacques, All the append/insert methods are called on the element to which the node should be added.